# How to convert my listView into dynamiclistview? I am referring to http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#dynamiclistview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to use this : [lib](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#dynamiclistview) to have my list items be deleted when user swipes them. But I can't seem to get how to convert my existing listView to DynamicListView. I've read the instructions given, it just says to add some code to the xml layout to convert listView into DynamicListView, but where should I put that code? In which xml file? I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what is given in wiki:

> To use the DynamicListView, include the following in your xml layout:

```
<com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
        android:id="@+id/dynamiclistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to make your current list the

```
<com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
        android:id="@+id/dynamiclistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and add the functionality as described with

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(myAdapter);
animationAdapter.setAbsListView(mListView);
mListView.setAdapter(animationAdapter);
```

creating your own adapter to plug in with your existing list view implementation. So Idk if you have your own adapter setup, you didn't provide any code along with this? So mainly though your list view will have to fall in line with the xml "@+id/dynamiclistview" for it to function. I recommend extending there implementation if you already have an Adapter built up, and just providing methodology for the swipe and delete functions.

EDIT:

Please note this is important `<com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView`
that you have this implemented and the library properly imported. (any questions ask)